# ValueError: time data "(0, '2022-06-14')" does not match format "(d, '%Y-%m-%d')

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

While parsing the data with the below code, I'm getting:

```
ValueError: time data "(0, '2022-06-14')" does not match format "(d, '%Y-%m-%d')".
```

Language: Python 3.x:

```
for i in data_1['Date'].iteritems():
    data_1.loc[i, 'Date'] = datetime.strptime(str(i),"(d, '%Y-%m-%d')").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Please Help me to resolve the problem!!

Comment: When you use iteritems() it yields a touple containing the index and the value. So in that "i" you don't have a date, you have the index! The first parameter of strptime() is supposed to be a date

Comment: I've tried str(i[1]),"%Y-%m-%d" also earlier but it is throwing an error: KeyError: "['2022-06-14'] not in index"

Comment: Replace `(d,` with `(0,`.

Comment: `iteritems` is a **Python 2** `dict` method — so I thnk your question is tagged incorrectly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, then update your question with specific details, simplified examples to support your explanation, and code/configuration/links you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `data_1` is a pandas DataFrame. Then the following would work:

```
for idx, row in data_1.iterrows():
    data_1.loc[idx, "Date"] = datetime.strptime(row["Date"], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Short explanation of what gone wrong:

- `df.iteritems()` would iterate through columns instead of rows
- Best practice for parsing string to datetime, would be to only include relevant information (which the numeric index is not)